# find the 10's complement of given number

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, decimal-expansion

## Question

> Find the $10$'s complement of decimal number $00,000,000$

#### My Approach

> $r^{'s}$ complement of $N$=$r^{n}-N$

where $n$= number of digitin $N$

Now $10^{'s}$ complement of $00,000,000$=

$10^{8}-00,000,000=100,000,000$

Everywhere answer is $00,000,000$

Am i Wrong?

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-0=0$ so you would like the tens complement to be $0$.  If you have eight digits of $0$s you don't store the ninth digit so ignore the leading $1$.

Comment: sir: it is one of the rules of *$r^{'s}$* complement  that $0$ has only one representation in *$r^{'s}$* complement .But my formula  to find the *$r^{'s}$* complement is right?

Comment: Your formula is right and for any other number than $0$ you will borrow from the ninth place to remove the $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :)